# ¿Hay alguna forma de poner círculos en java juntos como en la imagen, ya que no me deja?

Tags: java, java-awt

Estoy intentando dibujar círculos en java tal como se muestra en la imagen de GeoGebra. Hay un inconveniente: no me deja ponerlos juntos. ¿Hay alguna forma de ponerlo como en la imagen? ¿O estoy poniendo algún dato mal?

Adjunto imagen en geogebra y en java.

[image: Captura-Dibujar-Java.jpg]

[image: Captura-Panel.jpg]

CLASE DIBUJO

```
package ejemplografica;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Dibujo {
    
    public static void lugar( Graphics g, int x,int y, int ancho, int alto, boolean t)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fill3DRect(x, y, ancho, alto, t);
    }
    public static void aspersor(Graphics g, int x, int y, int ancho, int alto)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(x, y, ancho, alto);
    }
}
```

FORMULARIO PARA GRAFICAR

```
    private void CuadradoMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        Dibujo.lugar(mainPanel.getGraphics(), 100, 100, 100, 90, false);
        Dibujo.aspersor(mainPanel.getGraphics(), 85, 85, 30, 30);
        Dibujo.aspersor(mainPanel.getGraphics(), 85, 85+30, 30, 30);
        Dibujo.aspersor(mainPanel.getGraphics(), 85, 85+30*2, 30, 30);
        Dibujo.aspersor(mainPanel.getGraphics(), 85, 85+30*3, 30, 30);}

    private void Cuadrado1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
     repaint();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mira la siguiente imagen:

[image: https://blogsaverroes.juntadeandalucia.es/recursosdematematicas/cuadrado-y-circulo/]

Tu caso es el de la derecha. Estás inscribiendo un cuadrado en un círculo. Si prestas atención, el lado del cuadrado mide menos que el diámetro del círculo, por eso te queda más chico y ligeramente desplazado.

Lo que tienes que hacer es inscribir el círculo en un cuadrado (izquierda). El diámetro sí es igual al lado del cuadrado. Haz las mediciones de nuevo pero con este cuadrado.

Ese es el inconveniente con cada círculo.

---

Por cierto, quizá te interese más usar la función [`fillRect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect-int-int-int-int-) que [`fill3DRect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fill3DRect-int-int-int-int-boolean-)

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo